# What options do I have to do a cached searching in my objects with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

I have a MVC 5 app running with EntityFramework 6.

On of the pages will be search results returned based on a query from users. The data is not updating that offen and it would not be a problem if search results are cached.

I am using unity for dependency injection of the entity framework context. Its in the default case of giving a new instance on every controller (hence on every request).

What can I do to cache the search results?

Should I change such there are not returned a new context on every controller and let entity framework cache the objects?

Can I just enable some caching in MVC and leave it at that?

Comment: Anything else you need on this question? If answer helped please consider accepting and up voting. Thanks

Comment: Ye sorry about the delay, got busy with something else. THanks

Comment: No problem. I needed 3000 rep for next level :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at E[ntity Framework extended nuget package](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). We use it for Caching EF queries. Although we use EF5. If it doesn't work it may be just a case of getting its source and adjust a few namespaces

Alternatively just manually cache your EF result (make sure you have it fully loaded by enumerating to list). Either cache it without filtering (if you have huge variability) or cache filtered versions and just cache that in HTTP cache. Could also create a query service that gets your data for you. Could cache the data in the query service or alternatively if you want cleaner code you could use a decorator to wrap the query service to give you cached versions

Your context per request is the correct setup. [Every request should have a new context](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices.aspx). Don't try to have a long lived context it will cause you no end of troubles.

Could also enable page level output caching of MVC (and make sure you [cache based on parameters passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886838/how-do-i-configure-outputcache-page-attribute-for-varying-querystring-values)) However your mileage on that may vary depending on number and ranges of paramters

Comment: Thanks for the option link. I will figure out what suits my needs the best tomorrow. I am leaning to Page lvl caching as it sound like the easy way out and right now the search is just a query constructed based on one word. (simple simple search). Might go with one of the other options if a more sophisticated search is needed.

Comment: If the one word is frequently the same will help. It depends on the variability of the word. If it varys lots then cache the data and filter that with the word. Let me know if you need anything else. Done a fair amount of caching over the years with EF in different ways.